# Gradle DSL method not found

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am having problems compiling my app with Android Studio 1.5, The  issue  is that  when i am trying to run a project I am getting error.

`*Error (16, 0) Gradle DSL method not found*: 'android()'
        Possible causes:The project 'RTA' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.`

Comment: add please ypur build gradle file

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply change your `build.gradle` file.

Check if part:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
```

is on the top of your `build.gradle`. You can't have this code at that place because the android build plugin isn't loaded just yet.

You can define the compile version and build tools version in the app level `build.gradle`

Make sure that on top of this file you have:

```
   apply plugin: 'android'
```

Read also this: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-to-1-0-0

Hope it help

Comment: Thanks  piotrek for your valuable response but   its  Ddd not work for me.

Comment: add your build.gradle file in your post to check it